# Substring with repeating character

Tags: c#, substring

How I will substring this sample combobox items

```
E11-143 - America           -->    America 
JC - Political theory       -->    Political theory
```

I tried this:

```
string test = comboBox1.Text.Substring(comboBox1.Text.IndexOf('-') + 1).Trim();
```

But this is the result

```
E11-143 - America           -->    143 - America 
JC - Political theory       -->    Political theory
```

Comment: use `.LastIndexOf` instead of `IndexOf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx) to get the index of the last occurrence of a character:

```
string test = comboBox1.Text.Substring(comboBox1.Text.LastIndexOf('-') + 1).Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variation:

```
var str = "E11-143 - America";
var val = str.Split('-').LastOrDefault().Trim();
```

Comment: @Prix It is not safe to call Trim() on result of LastOrDefault() (it can return `null`).

Comment: Note that `Last` is good enough, since there's no way that `Split` will yield an empty sequence. Also, even if `LastOrDefault` returned `null`, the `Trim()` would raise a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes, but `Last` is exception prune.

Comment: What if the string is `JC - Political-theory`? I assume OP wants the last part after `" - "`. So he wants `Political-theory` not `theory`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan `Last` will produce an exception if the set is empty, which is not possible here because `Split` will never produce an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "E11-143 - America";
var newstr = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("-")+1).Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.IndexOf` + `Substring`. But you need to search for `" - "` instead  for `-` (note the white-spaces)

```
int index = text.IndexOf(" - ");
string result = null;
if(index >= 0)
     result = text.Substring(index + " - ".Length);
```

or `String.Split`

```
text.Split(new[]{" - "},StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
```

The `IndexOf` approach is more efficient whereas the `Split` is more readable.

Comment: You mean LastIndexOf ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: No, i'm not looking for `-` but for `" - "` (note the white-spaces)